# SFDC Probelm while viewing preview in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, pdf, preview

While previewing the document , it is showing no preview, please give input if possible , and i have pasted the code below

```
 handleDocumentView(event){
   console.log('view button called'); console.log(event.currentTarget.dataset.id);
   this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](
      { type: 'standard__namedPage', attributes: {
          pageName: 'filePreview', recordId: event.currentTarget.dataset.id, objectApiName: 'ContentVersion', actionName: 'view', }, 
          state: { selectedRecordId: event.currentTarget.dataset.id }, 
      }
   );
}
```

And image is also attached
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably passing the ContentVersion recordId, what you need to do is pass the ContentDocument recordId.